# Variance introduced by dropout

Tags: variance, covariance, covariance-matrix, uncertainty

I just read this paper [Sampling-free Epistemic Uncertainty Estimation Using Approximated
Variance Propagation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00598) and stumbled upon two points at the end of section 3.1 that I don't understand. Here, the authors state that:

> For the special case of the first noise layer in the network, we can
> either model the input noise from prior knowledge (i.e. sensor noise)
> or simplify it by assuming zero noise. In the latter case, the
> resulting covariance matrix will be diagonal given independent noise,
> resulting in: $\Sigma_{\vec{X}^i} = \text{diag}(\sigma_1^2, \cdots,
> > \sigma_n^2)$ where $n$ is the dimensionality of the activation vector
> and $\sigma_i^2$ is the variance of activation $i$.

Here I don't understand the following point: they say that you can assume zero noise but the resulting covariance matrix will be diagonal. How is this possible? If there is a signal (in this case the random vector $\vec{X}^i$) with zero noise, how can the covariance matrix have any nonzero elements?

> The variance introduced by the regular dropout, which follows a
> Bernoulli distribution, is given by $p(1 − p)a_i^2$, with $p$ defining
> the dropout rate and $a_i$ the mean activation of node $i$.

I find this part of the section even more confusing. How is it, that the variance introduced by dropout is $p(1 − p)a_i^2$ and not just $p(1 − p)$? Where does this expression for the variance come from? Why is the variance squared by the squared mean activation? And where do they get the mean activation $a_i$ from in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this section, they're discussing the behavior of a 'noise layer', which combines its input $X$ with random noise $Z$. For the first noise layer in the network, $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is assumed to be a fixed vector. $Z$ is an $n$-dimensional random vector with i.i.d. entries. For an additive noise layer, the activations $Y$ are produced by adding the noise to the input:

$$Y = X + Z$$

Alternatively, the noise layer may implement dropout. In this case, the entries of $Z$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli (with dropout rate $p$), and the activations are given by the Hadamard product of the input and noise vectors (i.e. by multiplying them element-wise):

$$Y = X \circ Z$$

> Here I don't understand the following point: they say that you can assume zero noise but the resulting covariance matrix will be diagonal. How is this possible? If there is a signal (in this case the random vector $\vec{X}^i$) with zero noise, how can the covariance matrix have any nonzero elements?

They're referring to the covariance matrix of the noise layer activations $Y$, not the input $X$. For the first additive noise layer, since $Y=X+Z$ and $X$ is assumed constant, the covariance matrix of $Y$ is equal to the covariance matrix of $Z$. And, since $Z$ has i.i.d. entries, the covariance matrix is diagonal.

> I find this part of the section even more confusing. How is it, that the variance introduced by dropout is $p(1 − p)a_i^2$ and not just $p(1 − p)$? Where does this expression for the variance come from? Why is the variance squared by the squared mean activation? And where do they get the mean activation $a_i$ from in the first place?

The wording of the paper seems slightly ambiguous to me, but I think we can understand it as follows. Consider the first dropout layer. The activation of the $i$th unit in the noise layer is:

$$Y_i = X_i Z_i$$

Suppose that that $X_i=a_i$ is the activation of the $i$th input unit (which is assumed constant, as above). [Therefore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties):

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y_i) = \operatorname{Var}(a_i Z_i) = a_i^2 \operatorname{Var}(Z_i)$$

Since $Z_i$ is Bernoulli as above, $\operatorname{Var}(Z_i) = p(1-p)$ and:

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y_i) = p (1-p) a_i^2$$

Comment: Is it possible to derive the expression for $Var(Y_i)$ using $\Sigma^{(i)} = J \Sigma_{\vec{Z}} J^T$ where $J(\vec{Y}^{(i-1)})$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $X_i$ and $\Sigma_{\vec{Z}}$ also a diagonal matrix with elements $p(1-p)$?